# Selecting a tab with jQuery tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I set up the jQuery Tab tools on my web application, and it's working fine to click between the tabs, but what I would like to do is be able to select a tab after another javascript function completes. I'm having trouble doing this successfully after reading through the documentation and searching.

I have a search function, and when someone searches, I'd like the search tab to be selected and come into view.

At the end of the search function:

```
var tabby = jQuery('#right-tabs').tabs();
tabby.tabs('select', 1); // switch to second
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="right1">
    <ul class="tabs" id="right-tabs"> 
        <li><a href="#" id="articles-tab">Articles</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#" id="search-tab">Search results</a></li> 
    </ul> 
    <div class="panes" id="right-panes">
        <div id="articles-panel"></div>
        <div id="search-results-panel"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I got a firebug error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined".

I also tried another approach... just manually setting/removing the classes, with this:

```
jQuery("ul#right-tabs a").removeClass('current');
jQuery("ul#right-tabs a#search-tab").addClass('current');
jQuery("div#articles-panel").hide();
jQuery("div#search-results-panel").show();
```

That works, but it creates a strange behavior, of not letting you click on any other tabs until you click on the selected tab, and then it will let you click the other ones.

So, I'm not exactly sure how to make jQuery tools cooperate with what I want to do. It should be simple, I'm considering bailing on this and just writing it from scratch. But if you guys have a way to make either approach work, or a better way, I would really appreciate it!

**UPDATE**

All I needed was:

```
var api = jQuery("ul#right-tabs").data("tabs");
api.click(1);
```

I was mistakenly finding examples for the jQuery tabs and not the jQuery tools tabs.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in jsFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything on the `select` method in the jQuery Tools tabs api documentation.  Are you sure that `select` is a valid method?  I was able to select a specific tab by doing this: '$("#right-tabs li a")[1].click()', but I would think there would be a method for this.

Comment: Fixed! The answer was with:                                              var api = jQuery("ul#right-tabs").data("tabs");
api.click(1);

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept it as answered. It makes your solution much more visible and will help others.

Comment: I will, but SO doesn't let you answer your own question until 8 hours later. So I updated my question in the mean time. Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I needed was:

```
var api = jQuery("ul#right-tabs").data("tabs");
api.click(1);
```

I was mistakenly finding examples for the jQuery tabs and not the jQuery tools tabs.