# Select jquery tools tab without knowing the index

Tags: javascript, jquery-tools

How can i select a tab from jquery tools, if i don't know the index?
I don't know the index, because some users will have 4 tabs and some other 5 or even more, depending on their application permissions.

I've found a similar problem here [Selecting a tab with jQuery tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072151/selecting-a-tab-with-jquery-tool) but it uses a index, which i'm not able to use, because i don't know the index of my tab

Comment: if you don't know the idex, then how you would to select a tab ? if you need "next" tab, find index of current one.

Answer (score 0):

When you build the tabs, keep a list of which ones your adding, and what there index is.

IE, app has options for tabs a, b, c and d.

User has tabs set to open as b/a/d (Assuming they can set the order as well as the tabs)

Somewhere in your code you must know what they have selected to show, and what order they are showing in, so keep an array like

```
var tabArray = ["b","a","d"];
```

and then to get the index, use...

```
var tabIndex = array.indexOf("a");
```

NOTE: indexOf doesn't work in older versions of IE, but there are work arounds to add it if needed, like the ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers).